# Get SOAP for PHP 5.6

Tags: apt, apache2, php, lamp

I am running my LAMP app, and update the modules through composer.

I am trying to install SOAP for php but I have a few issues. I have PHP 5.6.36

If I run `sudo apt-get install php-soap`
It installs SOAP for php 7. So SOAP is not well configured, and when I do php -i, I can see that SOAP is not activated.

When I run `sudo apt-get install php5.6-soap`
It is not able to find any package for that version. Thing I don't understand is that when I google, I see that a lot of people are using that command fine. Is it something missing in my repo?

I update my Ubuntu from 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Still not able to find the version of SOAP for php5.6.

Any help welcome, I am stuck on this for almost 2 days. Thanks for your help

Comment: Please include the error message you get after running `sudo apt-get install php5.6-soap`

Comment: hey Parto. I was getting that it was unable to find the package for php5.6-soap. I solved my problem, basically I needed to update to php7 to have php-soap working, looks like the package for 5.6 is not available for certain versions

Comment: @krishnaSF Please add an answer below and describe how you solved it.

Comment: Hi so solve the problem, i have migrated to PHP7. Didn't found any version compatible for PHP5, so after migrating to PHP7 everything was working fine